# How can I get All possible values of enum type in mysql through Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I want to populate my drop down with the values from one column in database and data type of that column is `ENUM` having values (A,B,C). I have read a lot of questions and answers suggesting the creation of an `ENUM` in java and then mapping it to the column.

But I think it is not consistent. What if I make a change in the database and forget to reflect that change in my Java enum? It could create a big blunder because it's totally static to make edits on both sides.

Are there any better solutions for tackling this situation? I want to get all possible values from the database column through hibernate, and NOT from a Java enum that reflects the column in my database.

Comment: what is the data type of the column on ur domain class?

Comment: just for now I have kept String. because I am searching for better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I believe there will be a better way but **try** this.*

in mysql to get description of a col you can use:

```
desc tableName colName
```

*e.g desc test name*
[image]

so to get this row in Hibernate:

```
final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("desc tableName colName");
List<Object[]> descRow = q.list().get(0);
```

*//then iterate over the entities*

Comment: @10sw33 yeah it is not